# How to properly position tooltips over an absolute positioned element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position, qtip2

I have a bunch of images positioned absolute that I'm trying to get tooltips to appear over based on the data attributes specified on the element. For some reason the positioning of the tooltip is always off. I've included a demo. Can anyone spot the issue?

```js
$("div.thing").each(function (i) {
  var objthis = this;
  $(this).qtip({
    show: 'click',
    hide: 'click',
    content: {
      text: 'hey'
    },
    position: {
      corner: {
        tooltip: 'topLeft',
        target: 'topLeft'
      },
      adjust: {
        x: $(objthis).data('left'),
        y: $(objthis).data('top')
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

div.thing {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="thing" data-top="50" data-left="20"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: dunno if it helps, but i believe your tooltip position is doubled (100-40 instead of 50-20) (maybe you should remove data-top and data-left in your HTML ?)

Answer (score 0):

By setting both the `offset` in the qtip settings, you're moving the tooltip too far away from the image. Try removing the offset:

```js
$("div.thing").each(function (i) {
  var objthis = this;
  $(this).qtip({
    show: 'click',
    hide: 'click',
    content: {
      text: 'hey'
    },
    position: {
      corner: {
        tooltip: 'topLeft',
        target: 'topLeft'
      },
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

div.thing {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="thing" data-top="50" data-left="20"></div>
</div>
```